# How do I get Photoshop to support RAWs from FZ2000?

Tags: photoshop, adobe-camera-raw, panasonic

I previously thought that RAW format is just a one format and any Ps version works with it. But now I know that different RAW formats from newer cameras are not supported by the Ps version that exists at the time the cameras is released.
Anyway, I found a [table](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-plug-supported-cameras.html) which what ACR and LR versions support this specific camera's RW2 files are mentioned. (It says ACR 9.8 & LR 6.8 support RW2s from the FZ2000, right?)
So, how can I know about what **Photoshop** version that supports FZ2000's RW2s? And, is the ACR (in this case, version 9.8) integrated in it?; do I need to get the ACR (9.8) separately?..

Answer (score 1):

If your camera needs Adobe Camera Raw 9.8, then you need Photoshop CC [any version]
CS6 & earlier do not support ACR 9.8
*Ref: Adobe KB: [Legacy version update information](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/legacy-version-updates.html)*

However, there is a workaround for earlier versions -
From the Adobe KB: [Photoshop or Lightroom doesn't support my camera](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/why-is-my-camera-not-supported.html)

> **What if I own an older version of Photoshop or Lightroom?**
>
> You do not have to buy a new version of Photoshop or Lightroom just to
>   get the latest camera support.
>
> Adobe provides backwards compatibility for the latest cameras for free
>   in Photoshop CS, CS2, CS3, CS4, CS5, and CS6 as well as Lightroom 1,
>   2, 3, 4, and 5, through the [Adobe DNG Converter](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adobe-dng-converter.html). With this tool,
>   you can easily convert camera-specific raw files from supported
>   cameras to a more universal DNG raw file.

Comment: Just be aware that there are a few caveats to converting image files in other raw formats to DNG. If all you ever use to edit images are Adobe products you'll likely never notice, but if you think you might ever want to use other editing tools you might want to preserve your raw files in the original format as well.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-compatible-applications.html) lists which versions of Adobe products work with which versions of Adobe Camera Raw. It is included in [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/79899/15871) to the question [How do I tell if ACR will work with my camera and how do I get the correct version for Photoshop?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/79876/how-do-i-tell-if-acr-will-work-with-my-camera-and-how-do-i-get-the-correct-versi/79899#79899)

If you choose to use *[Adobe DNG Convertor](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=5596)* to convert your raw files to a DNG version supported by an older version of *Photoshop*, be aware that the conversion *may* remove some of the functionality and flexibility you would have if you used a newer version of *ACR/LR/PS* to work with the raw files directly. This will probably be most noticeable with regard to color and noise profiles for newer cameras used with older versions of *ACR/LR/PS*. Again, it all depends on which camera (and more generally, which manufacturer) the raw files are coming from.