# Download RAW from Nikon D750 camera

Tags: nikon, raw

I recently change my settings on my camera to shoot in raw. Now I’m trying to download them to my computer and it’s saying there not accessible since they were shot in raw. And they will not download wirelessly on the Nikon app.

Comment: Have you try to download them from SD card?

Comment: Downloading them how, exactly? Nikon's software should not be an issue, some sort of auto-image-backup-er might not recognize them... And SnapBridge??? Something else for the Nikon App (On a phone?)

Comment: Possibly related to https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/79876/how-do-i-tell-if-acr-will-work-with-my-camera-and-how-do-i-get-the-correct-versi/79899#79899 ?

Comment: Related: [Is the full RAW file transferred with Nikon Wireless Mobile Utility App?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/92523)

Comment: Which Nikon app are you using and in which platform Mac or Windows and are trying you to send them from the camera or accessing them from the computer? Any error message or message from the app or the camera?

Comment: you could always just copy the NEF files manually from your card into the folder you store your images, and then synchronize them in Lightroom (or whatever other software you may be using) afterwards

Answer (score 1):

You **CAN** actually send the original raw files over wifi with Nikon Cameras. The transfer will take longer that tethered shooting thru a dedicated lan port. And you need at the computer ends an application that read raw files like Lightroom or Capture ONE and supports tethered shooting if you want to view the pictures.

You can even setup an FTP or SFTP server (on you Lan or Internet) to receive them.

**Nikon D750**: The user has to follow a process **in the camera** to **select and push** the selected photos to the computer over wifi. The process is explained in **Pg. 270** of the user's manual ([PDF download from Nikon](http://crossgate.nikonimglib.com/dsd_redirect/redirect.do?P=VAw4t18&R=17HBG54&L=7ev4o03&O=KNkXN00)).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it's not possible to transfer RAW Files via WiFi from your camera to another device, because the files are very large. For this reason, many cameras have the feature to take both file types, RAW and JPEG. Then you are able to transfer the smaller JPEG files for preview reasons to e.g. your mobile device. In post processing you are then able to edit the RAW files on your PC.