# How to access RAW image of Nikon D7200 in Lightroom 5.7 or Photoshop CC?

Tags: nikon, lightroom, photoshop, raw

I have Nikon D7200, I clicked all my pics in .NEF(RAW) format, now I am unable to access the images in Lightroom 5.7 and Photoshop cc, I tried to install plug-in in Photoshop cc, but some how failed to access the images. I prefer to access all images in lightroom 5.7.

Thanks
Atul Agarawal

Comment: Does an error message appear somewhere?

Comment: No Error message as such, While import both post processing tool does not recognize Raw file which are in .NEF format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell if ACR will work with my camera and how do I get the correct version for Photoshop?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/79876/how-do-i-tell-if-acr-will-work-with-my-camera-and-how-do-i-get-the-correct-versi)

Comment: See also [DNG converter doesn't convert, Photoshop CS2 doesn't open DNG](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52944/dng-converter-doesnt-convert-photoshop-cs2-doesnt-open-dng)

Comment: Same issue, different particulars: [Does Photoshop 7 support RAW file format?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45278/does-photoshop-7-support-raw-file-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Nikon D7200 raw files are only supported starting with Lightroom 6/ ACR 9.

If you can't or won't upgrade your Adobe products, you can still download their DNG Converter to convert the NEF's to DNG format, which should then be useable in older versions of Lightroom.

your mention of Photoshop CC implies that you should be able to upgrade it to the current version, in which case, it must be able to open the images. Check that you really have a recent version of Adobe Camera Raw installed.

Comment: While this is true, you can download Adobe Camera Raw updates free and easily from Adobe's site, no sign-in required.

Comment: @NoahL The most recent versions of ACR also require the most recent versions of Lr/Ps...

Comment: @MichaelClark really? I'm running Photoshop CC 14.0 and ACR 9.8. PS 14.0 was released in June 2013, ACR 9.8 was released December 2016.

Comment: Try using ACR 9.8 with any of these Adobe applications: https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-compatible-applications.html

Comment: Here's the place to start to understand the complexities of the entire issue: https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/troubleshoot-camera-raw-photoshop-photoshop.html

Comment: @ths, I will download DNG converter.

Answer (score 1):

Is just the meta data model name need to be fixed .

You can download https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/
(macos or window supported)

than updated the nef file

$ exiftool -Model="Nikon D5300" ./yourfile.nef

for the detail tutorial you can find in below link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEuqFD-0KsM

Comment: It's not quite that the metadata model needs to be **fixed**; rather, what you're suggesting is a **hack** of the images' metadata to get it to work, if one is unwilling / unable to update to a more recent Lightroom or Photoshop. Still, interesting suggestion!