# Which software is actually needed to update for Adobe Lightroom to support new cameras?

Tags: lightroom, adobe-camera-raw

I always thought that "[Adobe Camera Raw](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/using/supported-cameras.html)" is the software that maintains all the camera information and allows also Lightroom to read new camera's specific RAW files.

However, I have updated the "[Adobe Camera Raw and DNG Converter](https://supportdownloads.adobe.com/detail.jsp?ftpID=6971)" to Beta 12.4 but it does not seem to update Lightroom with the new cameras in the list. Is this a different software from "Adobe Camera Raw"?

[image]

I am having issues finding the right definitions what is what on the adobe websites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DNG convertor is standalone software, independent of any other software. Adobe camera RAW/Lightroom are part of Adobe Creative cloud.

So updating DNG convertor have nothing to do with updates of Adobe Creative cloud.
By definition (simplified):

- DNG convertor - convert RAW files to DNG, free
- Adobe Creative Cloud - Lightroom/Photoshop/etc. - photo manipulation
  software, currently subscription based

And Lightroom use own RAW engine so it need to be updated separately from Adobe Camera RAW update.

Comment: So is an update to camera raw fixing compatibility issues or does Lightroom itself need to be updated to support new cameras?

Comment: He implied that both need their separate updates as they are separate products.

Comment: @uncovery, Lightroom use own RAW engine so it need to be updated separately.

Comment: It's my understanding, based mostly on previous questions/answers here at Photo.SE for the last eight years or so, that LR uses the raw engine of ACR, but that the oldest versions of ACR are not supported by the newer versions of LR (and PS, etc.). One must have the version of ACR that supports a certain camera, and then one must use one of the versions of LR that support that version of ACR.

Comment: @MichaelC, LR may use RAW engine of ACR but the update is for entire product and do not depend of installation/update of ACR. Also I saw update for PS is "different" from update of ACR so (theoretically) you can update PS but not ACR and vice versa.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Please see [this help page at Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-compatible-applications.html) When LR is initially installed it includes ACR bundled with the LR installation. But ACR must be updated to include compatibility with new cameras. Eventually one will find that unless LR has also been periodically updated, a new version of ACR will not be supported by an older version of LR.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Please also see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/45283/15871) to [Does Photoshop 7 support RAW file format?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/45278/15871)

Comment: @MichaelC, my point is ACR which is bind to LR is not independent and as such can't be (normally) updated independently. You get update of all. And this version of ACR may be different from ACR plugin for PS

Comment: LR installs it, but not within LR. LR installs it as a separate application which it then calls upon. ACR can most definitely be updated independently of LR.